# Angular 5 reactive form - patchValue with FormArray not working

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have this reactive form in the Ionic3 framework, which I need to populate with data I retrieve from API. To do so I am using `patchValue` as I read somewhere that it is more reliable than `setValue`.

The problem I am facing is, it does not populate repeated form fields. To explain better I've created this [example code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-mfkbup).

I have tried other ways around like directly assigning data to the respective field instead of using `for` loop first, but that only populated 1 set instead of all 3.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong, or provide a better solution?

Thank you

Comment: Your code works fine. It's just that your populate method creates new FormGroups and populates them with patchValue(), but never pushes these new form groups to the form array.

Comment: patchValue() is not "more reliable". It does something different than setValue(). setValue expects a complete new value (containing a new value for every control of the form), whereas patchValue expects a partial new value (containing a new value for some of the controls of the form).

Comment: Thank you @JBNizet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example set your for loop on the home component to look like this

```
for(const rooms of resp.room_data){

      const roomNumberControl = this.createRooms();
      (<FormArray>this.informationForm.controls.room_numbers).push
      (roomNumberControl);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(rooms));
    }
```

Create rooms would just need to have some data in them but that will create on object for everyone in the array.  This is how I have done it in the past.

Comment: Thank you, that worked like charm, but it leaves the first field empty. Can you tell me how can I fix this?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-c5vapg

Comment: remove this.createRooms() from line 17 when the form is initialized you are populating it with a vaule

Comment: So silly of me, thank you so much again. You saved my day

Comment: Sure thing, glad I could help.